# Use network provided time in android (not default system time)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, ntp

I want to use the network provided time in android fragment. I know we can get the time using  calendar but it can be modified by changing system time. I tried using the class  `TimeManager` but android studio is not recognizing it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager

Is there any other method to implement the network time?

Answer (score 0):

Take time from any backend server

Comment: I am using firebase. How can I take time from it?